# Sublime 3 SQL Build System returns null when 'name' field in select

Tags: sublimetext3, sqlcmd

I have been working with the following sublime SQLCMD build system for a while with no issue.

```
{
"cmd": ["sqlcmd", "-S", "SERVER", "-d", "DATABASE", "-E", "-i", "$file"]
}
```

Today, after installing SQL Server Data Tools, I ran a very simple test query in Sublime:

```
select name from salesrep
```

The build results show only [Finished in 0.1s].. no error in the console. The same is true for this query:

```
select name, salesrepcode from salesrep
```

When I run this query:

```
select salesrepcode from salesrep
```

I get a full result set. I'm very confused about this. Does anyone know how I may be able to incorporate the 'name' field once again and see results?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you run the `sqlcmd` directly with the same parameters as ST3 would provide?

Comment: Good question - it actually runs as expected. No issues - full results.